# CleverTap API showing 512 error while running on Postman

Tags: clevertap

I am trying to send some data through an api using postman the data is sent successfully using Charged event but if I change the eventName to some other event it shows me an error code 512 and shows that only evtData can be nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CleverTap supports the item array for the Charged event only. That's why it is showing an error.